# `.joins` not working for has_many in Rails 3.2 on PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm upgrading a legacy project to Rails 3.2.1, but I'm having trouble with the new ActiveRecord query interface, specifically with the new `join` method.

I have a `User` model, that owns many `Podcast`s

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :podcasts
end

class Podcast < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My problem is that the `join` only works when called from the `belongs_to` side.

```
irb(main):005:0> Podcast.joins :user
  Podcast Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "podcasts".* FROM "podcasts" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "podcasts"."user_id"
  => []

irb(main):006:0> User.joins :podcast
  ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'podcast' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Weirdly enoguh, it all works if I change the relation to a `has_one`.

Relevant portion of my `schema.rb`

```
create_table "podcasts", :force => true do |t| 
  t.string   "name",         :default => "",   :null => false
  t.string   "url",          :default => "",   :null => false
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "last_updated"
  t.boolean  "active",       :default => true
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

The underlying DB is *PostgreSQL 9.1.2* and ruby is at *1.8.7-p357*.

Is this the intended behavior?

I know I can pass the SQL to `join`, but it would a considerable step back in terms of readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `:podcasts`:

```
User.joins :podcasts
```

The symbol you use with `joins` should match the symbol you use in the association. From the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations):

> ```
> class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :posts
> end
> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
>   belongs_to :category
>   has_many :comments
>   has_many :tags
> end
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **Joining a Single Association**
>
> ```
> Category.joins(:posts)
> ```